# Is there a way to send the feature file annotations in Karate via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, karate

We have a lot of feature files in our karate framework. We want to set up the ability to run any required feature file from Jenkins. Currently we are able to run the whole set of Feature files via Jenkins, but need to set up an ability to dynamically the required feature file annotation from JENKINS as part of a job.

Comment: this is what tags are for. read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#tags - and for jenkins, it is possible via `karate.options` but I recommend having a separate entry point (typically JUnit method that calls the `Runner` API) for each permutation-combination of features you want to run: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+tags+command+line - for advanced use-cases. you can always pass something from jenkins to java via environment variables or command line arguments and do whatever you want in the java code that calls karate

Comment: But then how will we pass this variable into the Runner file? @PeterThomas

Comment: via the command line or environment variables. you can work with someone who knows java well. for examples, read the docs please